# Получения данных из DataGrid WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Добрый день господа форумчане.
Возник вопрос, как при использовании паттерна MVVM в WPF при выделении строки в DataGrid получить её содержимое?
вот код:
1. ViewModel
получаем заполненный DataSet
Код C#

```
//в конструкторе
SongTable = _songDs.Tables["****"];

// свойство 
private DataTable _songTable;
        public DataTable SongTable
        {
            get { return _songTable; }
            set
            {
                if (_songTable == value) return;
                _songTable = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(SongTable.ToString());
            }
        }

  private List<Song> _selectSong;
        public List<Song> SelectSong {
            get { return _selectSong; }
            set
        {
            if (_selectSong == value) return;
            _selectSong = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectSong");
        } }
```

2.Model
Код XML

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True"  Height="67" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0"
                  Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479" ItemsSource="{Binding SongTable, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectSong,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Насколько я понимаю, при выделении строки в DataGrid должно сработать SelectedItem и данные передадутся в SelectSong, но этого не происходит
Подскажите пожалуйста!`введите код здесь`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SelectedItem - это одна строка, а Вы привязали к списку

Comment: Но задаю тот же DataRow или Song, вообще вызова свойства при выделении строки не происходит:( уже топчусь на одном месте и чую взгляд уже того на эту проблему:(
Подскажите что надо написать в свойстве...

Comment: Вот если оставить List<Song> то в рантайме приложение будет тихо ругаться на то что не может конвертировать значение в List. SelectedItem возвращает object попробуй его и принять... должно работать, возможно не тот тип ожидаешь.

Comment: ОО спасибо огромное:) продвинулся вперед:) что-то сразу про Object вообще не допер:(...а в итоге при проработке выяснилось, что надо задавать DataRowView:) теперь вот только уже подзастрял как DataRowView перевести в Song или List<Song>.....буду думать как-то:)

Comment: Для мультивыборки есть SelectedItems, а DataRowView это отголоски DataTable со всеми вытекающими....

Comment: а что за вытекающие?...где можно если, что более подробно почитать?:)
разобрался с преобразованием:) 
вот:
List<Song> d = new List<Song>();
Guid e = (Guid)_selectSong[0];
string g = _selectSong[1].ToString();
string f = _selectSong[2].ToString();
Song gg = new Song(songId: e, songName: g, songTime: int.Parse(f));
d.Add(gg );
Еще раз огромное спасибо:)

Comment: Еще раз Огромное спасибо:)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста.